# Parsing an array over multiple worksheets

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, variables

I am trying to breakdown an array of tickers on one sheet into multiple sheets.  I basically am trying to for loop through multiple sheets using the "i" variable as both a worksheet identifier and also a multiplier for how many tickers go on each sheet.

Can anyone spot the error I'm making here?  Or any other ways that you'd recommend to attack this?

"BreakdownCount" = the user inputted grouping size...in this case 200 as a test.

Thanks!

```
For i = 1 To BreakdownCount  
    UpperRange = 8 + (i - 1) * 200
    LowerRange = 8 + i * 200
    MsgBox UpperRange
    MsgBox LowerRange

    Worksheets("Data " & i).Range(Cells(8, 2), Cells(207, 2)).Value = Worksheets("Scanner - ALL").Range(Cells(UpperRange, 2), Cells(LowerRange, 2)).Value  
Next
```

Comment: What is it doing that is wrong?

Comment: Sorry Scott...I'll add that.  I'm getting a Run-time error '1004':  Application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to qualify **ALL** Range object with their parent sheet.  That includes the `Cells()` inside the Range():

```
For i = 1 To BreakdownCount  
    UpperRange = 8 + (i - 1) * 200
    LowerRange = 8 + i * 200
    MsgBox UpperRange
    MsgBox LowerRange

    Worksheets("Data " & i).Range(Worksheets("Data " & i).Cells(8, 2), Worksheets("Data " & i).Cells(207, 2)).Value = Worksheets("Scanner - ALL").Range(Worksheets("Scanner - ALL").Cells(UpperRange, 2), Worksheets("Scanner - ALL").Cells(LowerRange, 2)).Value  
Next
```

A Little short hand:

```
Dim wsOut as Worksheet
With Worksheets("Scanner - ALL")
    For i = 1 To BreakdownCount 
        Set wsOut =  Worksheets("Data " & i)
        UpperRange = 8 + (i - 1) * 200
        LowerRange = 8 + i * 200
        MsgBox UpperRange
        MsgBox LowerRange

        wsOut.Range(wsOut.Cells(8, 2), wsOut.Cells(207, 2)).Value = .Range(.Cells(UpperRange, 2), .Cells(LowerRange, 2)).Value  
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Ahhh I see.  Is there a way to do this for an entire workbook?  Or what is the best way to qualify this across all of the worksheets?  Thank you sir!

Comment: Scott...You are a genius.  Thank you SO much for this!

Comment: @rmunch123 Please remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.